# How does chromedriver start chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How does chromedriver starts chrome? Which command line does it use?

I need to know because I can reproduce a problem in chrome, but not when it is opened via the chromedriver and I am trying to find the difference.

to be specific - I am running chromedriver and then I run

```
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:9515/session -d '{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName": "chrome"}}'
```

and a new session is opened. 
I need to know the flags it uses.

Comment: Did you find out how chromedriver starts chrome?

Comment: @Robert Nope :|  The project closed a couple of weeks after..